# Firefox Retains Previous Value When Setting Select Value

Tags: jquery, firefox, select

I am trying to set the value of a dropdown using jQuery.

I have used

```
$('select[name="function"]').val('Major');
$('select[name="function"]').val('Major').change();
$('select[name="function"]').val('Major').trigger('change');
$('select[name="function"]').val('Major').trigger('update');
```

It sort of works as the value is set during page load however when I switch the tabs the dropdown reverts to the previous selection rather than the jquery set value. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put some breakpoints on your js code and see what's happening to the values when selecting.

Make sure the value in the options tags matches the value in the val method. You can also force the change like this:

```
$("#mydropdownlist").val("myvalue").change();
```

Comment: I've tried $('select[name="function"]').val('Major').change(); AND  $('select[name="function"]').val('Major').trigger('change'); it still reverts to the old value when I switch tabs.